# How to shrink flex items height to fit container heights

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to display a layout below in flex .

[image]

I have divs of equal width and height. I want to achieve the layout out below. By placing one item on the left and the remaining four fit on the right container and maintaining the same container height in the process . Thats the one on the left increase to fill the left height and width and the other right size of the container is shared among the four items.

```css
.trades {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.trade-panel {
  flex: 1;
}
.layout-5-2 {
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}
.layout-container-5-2-1 {
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 0 0 48%;
  display: flex;
}
.layout-container-5-2-2 {
  flex: 0 0 48%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="trades">
  <div class="layout-5-2">
    <div class="layout-container-5-2-1">
      <div class="trade-panel">item 1</div>
      <div class=" trade-panel">item 2</div>
      <div class="trade-panel">item 3</div>
      <div class=" trade-panel">item 4</div>
    </div>

    <div class="layout-container-5-2-1">
      <div class="trade-panel">vertical item.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My layout displays close to what i was expecting.with four to in the container to the right and one item to the left. However, The trades container scroll vertically to accommodate the four trades height. The trades does not shrink to fit into the right container thats `.layout-container 5-2-2`. Please how do i shrink the four to fix in the container heights ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #2A3052;
}
.left {
  flex: 1;
  background: #9497A8;
  margin: 10px;
}
.right {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.box {
  flex: 1;
  background: #9497A8;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem is `left` and boxes are boxes/items of equal heights and size. Therefore , the four items in the `right` expand the heights beyond the container heights there by causing a vertical scroll. The layout is fine. But the items does not fit.

Comment: If you add content to one box in `right`div,  the `left` div will match its height, so they will be equal in height https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/659/ or multiple boxes https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/660/

Comment: it does match the height but with a vertical scroll. I am looking for a way to shrink the items to the left and make them fit in the container. Nonetheless , thank you your code above is very helpful.