# How do i achieve the layout below in flex - css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

We have a flex container containing 5 boxes and i was asked to displayed them like the image below.

[image]

I was able to achieve similar layout by placing another two containers  inside the parent container. like below.

as discussed and answered  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911248/how-to-shrink-flex-items-height-to-fit-container-heights/36911397#36911397) . However, considering the project is existing , that is said to have introduced a lot of complexity that that when we adopt , would force changes in the structure of our js classes. I am now tasked with achieving the same by placing them in one single container.

```
.layout-5-3 {
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
}

.layout-5-3 > div:nth-child(1) {
    flex-basis: 48%;
}  

.layout-5-3 > div:nth-child(2),
.layout-5-3 > div:nth-child(3),
.layout-5-3 > div:nth-child(4),
.layout-5-3 > div:nth-child(5) {
    flex-basis: 48%;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

and in my html

```
<div class="layout-5-3">
  <div class="box">Box1</div>
  <div class="box">Box2</div>
  <div class="box">Box3</div>
  <div class="box">Box4</div>
  <div class="box">Box5</div>
</div>
```

I was expecting my first child to the placed on the left and the remaining four occupying the other half space. Considering my basis above. Please is there any way i can achieve this without introducing another flex container inside the parent container ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but would require fixed heights on the parent and defined widths on the children...and it would still be buggy in various browsers in various ways.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/aNRyNL)

```css
.layout-5-3 {
  display: flex;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 250px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
.layout-5-3 > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.layout-5-3 > div:nth-child(1) {
  width: 48%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.layout-5-3 > div:nth-child(2),
.layout-5-3 > div:nth-child(3),
.layout-5-3 > div:nth-child(4),
.layout-5-3 > div:nth-child(5) {
  width: 48%;
  flex: 1;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout-5-3">
  <div class="box">Box1</div>
  <div class="box">Box2</div>
  <div class="box">Box3</div>
  <div class="box">Box4</div>
  <div class="box">Box5</div>
</div>
```